# the program can't start because libgstreamer-0.10.dll is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dll, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am trying to create new project of gstreamer.
I downloaded the SDK and succeeded to run the tutorials, but when I create a new project:

```
File -> New -> Project ->  GStreamer SDK Project
```

copy the content of the (working) tutorial to my new project and launch it, I constantly get this error:

```
the program can't start because libgstreamer-0.10.dll is missing from your computer
```

am I missing something here?

thanks!

Comment: have you looked into your c:\windows\system32 directory to see if you have libgstreamer-0.10.dll ?

Comment: You need to set the path in the environment from where you are running     the project to the directory where dll is present

Comment: where can I find it (the path changing) in visual studio..?