# Visual Studio 2013 - Qt5 - Gstreamer: "libgstreamer-0.10-0.dll is missing from you computer" even though I correctly installed Gstreamer

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, dll, gstreamer-0.10

**A [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22036451/the-program-cant-start-because-libgstreamer-0-10-dll-is-missing) was already asked on stackoverflow, yet nobody answered, so I'm asking again.**

I followed all steps in http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows

Therefore, I believe that I correctly installed Gstreamer SDK + Devel on my computer. I followed the steps to set the enviromental variable: GSTREAMER_SDK_ROOT_X86_64

On Visual Studio I created a new Qt5 project, I set up the property sheet for gstreamer, yet when I run my application (still a basic Qt app with gst_init called) an error occurs saying:

> The program can't start because libstreamer-0.10-0.dll is missing from your computer.

Some say that the dll must be in `Windows/System32` or `SysWOW64` yet there is no such file there. That dll is by default found in `gstreamer_root_sdk_folder/bin`.

Comment: When you say "when I run my application an error occurs", do you mean on debug mode or by executing .exe?

Comment: @DYangu in Visual Studio when I press play in "Release Mode". You solve my problem with the answer below though! thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your app out of your develop environment (directly by clicking .exe generated file) you have to emplace your dlls in the same folder where your app.exe file is, unless you compile it with static libraries.

You have to look for `libstreamer-0.10-0.dll` in the Gstreamer SDK install folder (gstreamer_root_sdk_folder/bin as you pointed out), then copy and paste it in the same folder where your app.exe file is. Try to run again.

Maybe you will have to add some missing dlls after solve this. You can do it by following the same process for all the missing ones.